# How to specify generic type for method dynamically in context (without reflection if possible)

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

So is it possible to specify a generic type for a method dynamically in C#? I am not talking about using reflection, but with just C#.

Example:

```
internal class MyRepository
{
  async Task<IEnumerable<WhateverClass>> GetItemsFor<T>(int entityId, int itemId, params string[] keys)
    where T : class, IEntity
  {
    // do whatever
  }
}

interface IEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

internal class Foo : IEntity
{
  // whatever
}
```

Now my problem is that I will supply a `string` "foo" as `internal class Foo` because `Foo` is internal and cannot be accessed by my other projects (which is intended). But it is externally known as `string` "foo".

Now I want to call following method (which is public).

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<WhateverClass>> GetItemsFor(string forAsString, int entityId, int itemId, params string[] keys)
{
  var forAsType = forAsString switch
  {
     "foo" => typeof(Foo) // or what is needed here
  };

  return await _myRepository.GetItemsFor<forAsType>(entityId, itemId, keys); // this is not possible. How can I make this work?
}
```

Because the generic `T` is accessing a `DbSet` of type `T` I need to able to supply this in context.

So how can I solve this puzzle? Reflection is not forbidden but I am wondering if there is a "native" way. Or a respectable way with reflection

#### Edit 1:

`WhateverClass` has a correlation to `IEntity`. Let's say I want to set a `bool` based on if the `IEntity` is in a collection. This is abstracted a lot, but it is of no use to type all the context here.

```
public class WhateverClass
{
  public bool Enabled { get; set }
}
```

Comment: What is `WhateverClass` here? Is that expected to depend on `for` as well? (So would you expect it to return a `Task<IEnumerable<Foo>>` if called with "foo" as a first argument?)

Comment: @JonSkeet no whatever is a public class which has a correlation to `IEntity`. But because `Foo` is internal I cannot return a `IEnumerable<T>` because that is not allowed

Comment: How does `WhateverClass` relate to "Foo"?

Comment: @Llama I don't think that is important for the question. In my edit I explained that.

Comment: @Llama right, I am not the only one working on this project and a refactor is not going to happen unfortunately. If this was my personal project it would've been created a bit different. So the question stands, "what is a respectable way with reflection"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use a generic method which you call from your switch expression. That can be a nested method for brevity. That would avoid duplication, but also avoid reflection. For example:

```cs
public Task<IEnumerable<WhateverClass>> GetItemsFor(
    string forAsString, int entityId, int itemId, params string[] keys)
{
    return forAsString switch
    {
       "foo" => Impl<Foo>(),
       "bar" => Impl<Bar>(),
       _ => throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown 'for' value: {forAsString}");
    };

    async Task<IEnumerable<WhateverClass>> Impl<T>() =>
        await _myRepository.GetItemsFor<T>(entityId, itemId, keys);
}
```

You still need the switch expression, but it's probably nicer than using reflection.

Comment: I like you approach, but will not work as you typed it. I've adopted your thinking and got a working version. Need to store the output of the switch in a `Func<int, int, string[], Task<IEnumerable<WhateverClass>>>`. Then call that method later. See: https://prnt.sc/111emf5 Thanks.

Comment: @Roy: Why would it not work as I typed it? (I had a small typo on the return type of the method, but otherwise I'd expect it to work...) In general, any time you say something doesn't work, it's worth providing details (e.g. compilation error, exception etc). Otherwise the obvious next question is pretty much always going to be asking for details.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your original post and didn't see that `Impl` was a inline function. Other then that I didn't see the use in extending the functionality to a function while we could also call the repository directly. that is why I provided my own solution based on your answer.

Comment: @RoyBerris: I personally find my approach easier to read, and there's less text duplicated for each item (`Impl` vs `_repository.GetSummaryList`). Both will work, of course... I'm glad there wasn't actually a problem with my solution after all. (Again though, I'd recommend giving more details than "will not work" in any future similar situation.)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible without reflection. You would need to use reflection to get the MethodInfo of the generic method you want to call, then use the .MakeGenericMethod() call to apply the 'foo' type and call it using .Invoke()

Also, this is returning an enumerable of what exactly? If foo is internal then what would the consumer expect?

I also expect that what you are doing entirely violates the repository pattern it looks like you're using. The consumer would not be expected to know which types it can pass to a method. A repository should be for a specific data set.

Comment: My repository is for a specific data set. This approach is for a advanced filtering system for our database where a filter can be applied to a collection of entities. Final step in the puzzle is making a link from our CMS to the actual filter that has to be applied. Because our data layer is internal I have to use DTO's. But I do need to know for which specific `IEntity` I am getting the filters. That is what `T` is for